# What 'adb backup' stores? And what are its rules?

Tags: android, backup, adb, galaxy

I just found a suggestion for backing up a device. Running this:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\NAME\backup.ab
```

I am not an Android developer so I'm not familiar with all these commands (`-apk -shared` etc).

1. What data this backup stores/has in it? Is there any Google article related to this?
2. Can I use this backup and restore it to other Android version(API level)? 
   Backup 4.1.2 and restore the backup on 4.3?
3. Can I use this backup and restore it to other Android Device? Backup Galaxy 2, and restore on Galaxy 4?